# docker-compose: varnish+apache2 return a 503 error `Backend fetch failed`

Tags: docker, docker-compose, varnish

I am trying to run a very simple `Docker-compose.yml` file based on `varnish` and `php7.1+apache2` services:

```
version: "3"
services:
  cache:
    image: varnish
    container_name: varnish
    volumes:
      - ./default.vcl:/etc/varnish/default.vcl
    links:
      - web:webserver
    depends_on:
      - web
    ports:
      - 80:80
  web:
    image: benit/stretch-php-7.1
    container_name: web
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./index.php:/var/www/html/index.php
```

The `default.vcl` contains:

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
  .host = "webserver";
  .port = "8080";
}
```

I encountered the following error when browsing at `http://localhost/`:

```
Error 503 Backend fetch failed

Backend fetch failed
Guru Meditation:

XID: 9

Varnish cache server
```

The `web` service works fine when I test it at `http://localhost:8080/`.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure varnish to communicate with "web" on port "80" rather than "webserver" on port "8080".

The "web" comes from the service name in your compose file. There's no need to set a container name, and indeed that breaks the ability to scale or perform rolling updates if you transition to swarm mode. Links have been deprecated in favor of shared networks that docker compose will provide (links are very brittle, breaking if you update the web container). And `depends_on` does not assure that the other service is ready to receive requests. If you have a hard dependency to hold varnish from starting until the web server is ready to receive requests, then you'll want to update the entrypoint with a task to wait for the remote port to be reachable and have a plan for how to handle the web server going down.

The port 80 comes from the container port. There is no need to publish port 8080 on the docker host if you only want to access it through varnish, and this would be a security risk to many. Containers communicate directly to the container port, not back out to the host and mapped back into a container.

The resulting compose file could look like:

```
version: "3"
services:
  cache:
    image: varnish
    container_name: varnish
    volumes:
      - ./default.vcl:/etc/varnish/default.vcl
    ports:
      - 80:80
  web:
    image: benit/stretch-php-7.1
    volumes:
      - ./index.php:/var/www/html/index.php
```

And importantly, your varnish config would look like:

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
  .host = "web";
  .port = "80";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your accurate answer, your code is working fine.
However I would like to keep my "web" server running with port mapping `8080:80` in order to be able to test/debug to access my app directly (without varnish).
When I set `.port = "8080";` in the varnish config file, I get the same error as before.
How can shall I proceed?

Comment: @ben.IT containers do not talk to the host published port. To communicate between varnish and your web server container that is listening on port 80 inside the container, use port 80 in your varnish config.